# Groovy, HTMLUNIT and Javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, groovy, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit and groovy to perform a lot of web automation. I'm stuck when attempting to press the "OK" button on a javascript popup alert window  (not a normal browser window). I've set up ConfirmHandler - I think correctly - but the button still is not being pressed.

This is what I have currently:

```
conn = new WebClient(javaScriptTimeout:1000)
conn.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)
conn.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
conn.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

ConfirmHandler okayHandler = new ConfirmHandler() {
    boolean handleConfirm(Page page,String message) {
        return true
    }   
}

def page = conn.getPage(url)
def form = page.getFormByName("loginForm");

// code to login here - won't bore you with it

if (login failed) { // <-- this isn't the actual if statement, but need to remove for security purposes
    println "\n\nNeed to hit the okayHandler here"
    okayResult = conn.setConfirmHandler(okayHandler)
    println "\n\nOkay Result: ${okayResult}"
}
```

The things I notice:

1. The okayHandler method seems to be run
2. The value of "okayResult" is null
3. I can verify manually that the actual button has not been pressed

So, either my ConfirmHandler is incorrect, I'm calling it incorrectly, or my understanding of the javascript alert window is off. My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong with ConfirmHander?
2. Is there a better way to handle the javascript alert window? All I need to do is acknowledge it by pressing "ok".

==============

Here is my browser setup

public void setupBrowser() {

```
conn = new WebClient(javaScriptTimeout:1000)
conn.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)
conn.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
conn.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

AlertHandler myAlertHandler = new AlertHandler() {

    void handleAlert(Page page,String message) {
        println "\n\nClosing login alert message"
    }

}
```

}

Here is how I am attempting to handle the alert:

conn.myAlertHandler(handleAlert(resultPage,errorMessage))

And here is the error message:

FAIL - Unexpected exception: No signature of method: Groovy_charterLogin_Test.handleAlert() is applicable for argument types: (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage, java.lang.String) values: [HtmlPage('pagestuffhere'),passedErrorMesageHere]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the confirm handler before the alert opens; in your case you can do this directly after the construction and make sure with the real browser you are facing a confirm dialog (window.confirm(....)).

Comment: Thanks RBRi. You've given me some more to think about, notably that the window is an alert() window, not a confirm. That directed me to using AlertHandler instead, but I'm still Not Getting It. I'm trying everything I know.

Comment: Here is my browser setup

public void setupBrowser() {

 conn = new WebClient(javaScriptTimeout:1000)
 conn.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)
 conn.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    conn.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    
 AlertHandler myAlertHandler = new AlertHandler() {
  
  void handleAlert(Page page,String message) {
   println "\n\nClosing login alert message"
  }
  
 }
 
}

Here is how I am attempting to handle the alert:

conn.myAlertHandler(handleAlert(resultPage,errorMessage))

Comment: Bah, I'll put these comments in the main question